# Problem using answers and tasks packages

Tags: answers, tasks

I am trying to create questions (using `answers` package)  with several subquestions using the `tasks` package. Each question has a solution wich is to be typeset at the end of the document using functionality of the `answers` package.

My problem is that the solutions are not numbered properly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{answers}
\usepackage{tasks}

\Newassociation{solution}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans2]

\section{Exercises}

\begin{exercise}\label{xrc:one}
Exercise without tasks
\begin{solution}
Solution without tasks
\end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{xrc:two}
Statement of the second exercise

\begin{tasks}[counter-format= {tsk[a].) }, label-offset = {2em}, label-format ={\bfseries},label-width={1.5em}](3)
\task First task
\task Second task
\task Third task
\end{tasks}

\begin{solution}
Solutions to the second exercise

\end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{xrc:two}
Statement of the third exercise

\begin{tasks}[counter-format= {tsk[a].) }, label-offset = {2em}, label-format ={\bfseries},label-width={1.5em}](3)
\task First task
\task Second task
\task Third task
\task Fourth task
\task Fifth task
\task Sixth task
\end{tasks}

\begin{solution}
Solutions to the third exercise


\end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\section*{Solutions}\label{svar}

\input{ans2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not a problem related to `tasks`: any `\refstepcounter{...}` in the same place will cause the same problem…

Comment: Welcome to TeX.sx, by the way :)

Comment: try to add `
\addtocounter{exercise}{-1}\refstepcounter{exercise}` just before each `\begin{solution}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem directly related to the `tasks` package – any `\refstepcounter{…}` in the exercise before the `solution` environment causes the same problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{solution}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}[section]

\newcounter{test}
\renewcommand\thetest{test:\arabic{test}}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans2]

\section{Exercises}

\begin{exercise}\label{xrc:one}
  Exercise without \verb+\refstepcounter+
\begin{solution}
  Solution without \verb+\refstepcounter+
\end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{xrc:two}
\refstepcounter{test}
Statement of the second exercise
\begin{solution}
  Solutions to the second exercise
\end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}\label{xrc:three}
Statement of the third exercise
\refstepcounter{test}
\begin{solution}
  Solutions to the third exercise
\end{solution}
\end{exercise}

\Closesolutionfile{ans}

\section*{Solutions}\label{svar}

\input{ans2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can “repair” this by setting `\@currentlabel` to the exercise number again using

```
\addtocounter{exercise}{-1}\refstepcounter{exercise}
```

directly before the `solution` environment. With the `etoolbox` package and its `\AtBeginEnvironment` you can even repair this without having to add the code before each and every solution. Add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{solution}{\addtocounter{exercise}{-1}\refstepcounter{exercise}}
```

to your preamble (but after `\Newassociation{solution}{Solution}{ans}` of course).